# Why can I use a function to assign a value to a constant?

Tags: c++, constants

Why is the following code allowed in C++ when PI is a constant and determined at compile time while 4*atan(1) is only determined at runtime.

```
int main(){
    const double PI = 4*atan(1);
    std::cout << PI << std::endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

Where have I got it wrong?

Comment: you can only assign values to a const variable at the time of their declaration and that value can be determined at run time also.So there is nothing wrong with what you have done.If you try to change it again it will generate an error.

Comment: `const` doesn't mean it has to be determined at compile-time. It just means it doesn't change at run-time. Honestly, this is just bad naming of `const` and `constexpr`. The `const` in each of them means something entirely different. (Nonetheless, `4*atan(1)` *could* be evaluated at compile-time anyway).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a not-`constexpr` function to initialize that constant, because *it is not a compile-time-constant*, but only a `const`-qualified variable.

Most `math.h`-functions cannot be `constexpr` unfortunately, because they can set `errno`.
Error on coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07a87519a0cdab07

Answer (score 0):

This is an initialization, not an assignment. You are not changing the value of the constant, you are just initializing it to a certain value. This is correct and does not violate the constness property expressed by `const`.

`const` here does not mean "the value of this local variable is known at compile time". It means "the value of this local variable will not change".

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is able to evaluate `4*atan(1)` at compile-time. This is true for `atan` and all other `constexpr` functions.

You can enforce this by declaring your value as a `constexpr` too:

```
constexpr double PI = 4*atan(1);
std::cout << PI << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

`const` does not mean that "you have to initialize this with a literal". It means that "you can't change this value after initialization".

Answer (score 0):

Just to extends most of the answer.

Note the difference between `initialization` and `assignment`.

```
const int num = 3; // This is initialization

int toto = 0;
toto = num; // This is assignment
```